# Upgrade Ejabberd MySQL Schema to the new_sql_schema

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ejabberd

I am migrating my server to a new server.

I am looking to host two domains on the same server needing the new schema. The schema I am running is the old one.

How would I go about upgrading this? Can I export the database and manipulate it to adhere to the new schema somehow?

I have `ejabberd` running on `version 20.04` and I have one development machine (destination) on `version 20.07`.

Answer (score 0):

Support for upgrading PostgreSQL was added in ejabberd 18.03, and explained here: https://www.process-one.net/blog/ejabberd-18-03/

Nowadays the source code that implements that feature, and its documentation, doesn't mention what SQL databases are supported, so I hope MySQL is also supported.
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-admin-update-sql

You can try it, and comment here if it works for MySQL too.

Comment: Could you link to the source code for this upgrade script? Maybe I could run manually the upgrade on the CLI?

Comment: I found it... https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_admin_update_sql.erl 

But I think I will not try to do this manually. Maybe wait or convert to PostgreSQL... :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it does not work for MySQL (tried it). :(

```
root@collaboration:~# ejabberdctl update_sql
Converting mysql DB is not supported
```

I will post a new question to dig a little more into my problem. I was looking to do a quick fix but it might be more complicated than that.